# Pattern Definition for two letters, an underscore and value from 0-40

Tags: xml, xsd

I need to define a restriction pattern in an XSD which restricts the possible content of an element to DB_ and a Number from 0 to 40. At the moment I get an xsd validation error.
The Elements should look the following

```
<DB>DB_00</DB>
<DB>DB_01</DB>
<DB>DB_02</DB>

   ...

<DB>DB_39</DB>
<DB>DB_40</DB>
```

The Schema i have defined so far:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <xs:element name="DB">
          <xs:complexType>
               <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="DB_([0-40])"/>
               </xs:restriction>
          </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Thanks for the help!

PS : Please be lenient this is my first post here :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="DB" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:pattern value="DB_(0?[1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|40)"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: It is failing on `<DB>DB_00</DB>`

Comment: you are right, I've missed that part. This will make the regex less complex. Your solution is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks to you both, I really appreciate the effort you made. I hope you have a great weekend!!!

Answer (score 1):

First the XML shall be well-formed. Root element is missing.

**XML**

```
<root>
    <DB>DB_00</DB>
    <DB>DB_01</DB>
    <DB>DB_02</DB>
    <DB>DB_39</DB>
    <DB>DB_40</DB>
</root>
```

Regular expression numeric range is composed of two parts:

1. 00 to 39
2. 40

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="DB"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="DB" type="myType"/>

    <xs:simpleType name="myType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="DB_([0-3]{1}[0-9]{1}|40)"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```